# Drawing on a JPanel from multiple places

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, 2d

I'm currently working on a 2D game in Java for school. We have to use an Abstract Factory design pattern. For the 2D implementation I use a factory as follows:

```
public class Java2DFact extends AbstractFactory {
    public Display display;
    private Graphics g;
    public Java2DFact() {
        display = new Display(2000, 1200);
    }


    @Override
    public PlayerShip getPlayership()
    {
        return new Java2DPlayership(display.panel);
    }
```

In my display class I create a JFrame and Jpanel

```
public class Display {
    public JFrame frame;
    public JPanel panel;
    public int width, height;

    public Display(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("SpaceInvaders");
        frame.setSize(1200,800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        panel = new JPanel(){
           @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
               super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        panel.setFocusable(true);
        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Now from my main gameloop I call the visualize method inside the Java2DPLayership class to visualize my Playership

```
public class Java2DPlayership extends PlayerShip  {
    private JPanel panel;
    private Graphics2D g2d;
    private Image image;
    private BufferStrategy bs;


    public Java2DPlayership(JPanel panel) {
        super();
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    public void visualize()  {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Bee.gif"));
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
            //g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            //g.fillRect(10, 10, 12, 8);
            g.drawImage(image, (int) super.getMovementComponent().x, (int) super.getMovementComponent().y, null);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            g.dispose();
            panel.repaint();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to pass around the JPanel to every entity and let it draw its contents onto the panel before showing it. However I can't seem to figure out how to do this. When using this approach by changing the Graphics of the panel I get a lot of flickering.

Comment: You should only draw from the context of `paintComponent` which you override in a JPanel .  No where else.  That means once in `paintComponent` you can call other methods and pass the graphics context as an argument.  And keep your painting logic as short (time wise) as possible each time repaint is called to avoid holding up the Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fully functional, albeit simple example, I wrote some time ago. It just has a bunch of `balls` bouncing off the sides of the panel.  Notice that the `render` method of the `Ball class` accepts the graphics context from `paintComponent`.  If I had more classes that needed to be rendered, I could have created a `Renderable` interface and have each class implement it.  Then I could have a list of `Renderable` objects and just go thru them and call the method. But as I also said, that would need to happen quickly to avoid tying up the EDT.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Bounce extends JPanel {
   private static final int    COLOR_BOUND  = 256;
   private final static double INC          = 1;
   private final static int    DIAMETER     = 40;
   private final static int    NBALLS       = 20;
   private final static int    DELAY        = 5;
   private final static int    PANEL_WIDTH  = 800;
   private final static int    PANEL_HEIGHT = 600;
   private final static int    LEFT_EDGE    = 0;
   private final static int    TOP_EDGE     = 0;
   private JFrame              frame;
   private double              rightEdge;
   private double              bottomEdge;
   private List<Ball>          balls        = new ArrayList<>();
   private Random              rand         = new Random();
   private List<Long>          times        = new ArrayList<>();
   private int width;
   private int height;
   
   public Bounce(int width, int height) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      frame = new JFrame("Bounce");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(this);
      addComponentListener(new MyComponentListener());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      rightEdge = width - DIAMETER;
      bottomEdge = height - DIAMETER;
      for (int j = 0; j < NBALLS; j++) {
         int r = rand.nextInt(COLOR_BOUND);
         int g = rand.nextInt(COLOR_BOUND);
         int b = rand.nextInt(COLOR_BOUND);
         Ball bb = new Ball(new Color(r, g, b), DIAMETER);
         balls.add(bb);

      }
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return new Dimension(width, height);
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Bounce(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT).start();
   }

   public void start() {
      /**
       * Note: Using sleep gives a better response time than
       * either the Swing timer or the utility timer. For a DELAY
       * of 5 msecs between updates, the sleep "wakes up" every 5
       * to 6 msecs while the other two options are about every
       * 15 to 16 msecs. Not certain why this is happening though
       * since the other timers are run on threads.
       * 
       */
     Timer timer = new Timer(0,(ae)-> {repaint();
         for (Ball b : balls) {
            b.updateDirection(); 
         }} );
      timer.setDelay(5); // 5 ms.
      timer.start();
   }
   
  
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      
      for (Ball ball : balls) {
         ball.render(g2d);
      }
   }

   class MyComponentListener extends ComponentAdapter {
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {
         Component comp = ce.getComponent();
         rightEdge = comp.getWidth() - DIAMETER;
         bottomEdge = comp.getHeight() - DIAMETER;
         for (Ball b : balls) {
            b.init();
         }
      }
   }
   class Ball {
      private Color  color;
      public double  x;
      private double y;
      private double yy;
      private int    ydir = 1;
      private int    xdir = 1;
      private double slope;
      private int    diameter;

      public Ball(Color color, int diameter) {
         this.color = color;
         this.diameter = diameter;
         init();
      }

      public void init() {
         // Local constants not uses outside of method
         // Provides default slope and direction for ball
         slope = Math.random() * .25 + .50;
         x = (int) (rightEdge * Math.random());
         yy = (int) (bottomEdge * Math.random()) + diameter;
         xdir = Math.random() > .5 ? -1
                                   : 1;
         ydir = Math.random() > .5 ? -1
                                   : 1;
         y = yy;
      }

      public void render(Graphics2D g2d) {
         g2d.setColor(color);
         g2d.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, diameter, diameter);
      }

      public void updateDirection() {
         x += (xdir * INC);
         yy += (ydir * INC);
         y = yy * slope;
         if (x < LEFT_EDGE || x > rightEdge) {
            xdir = -xdir;
         }
         if (y < TOP_EDGE || y > bottomEdge) {
            ydir = -ydir;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing, How can I draw a single ball at the center  of the frame and move it with button click

Comment: Warning: The field times has been declared but never used

Comment: I got a button for up, down, left and right. When user presses the respective direction it needs to move in that direction. Would appreciate it if you edited to include that

Comment: First, I won't be updating this answer as it's frowned upon by admins.  You need to ask a question with your attempt at doing this.  Since you're relatively  new to SO, check out [ask] for more information.

Comment: can you write the code on some fiddler and then I jus cut, refactor the main class name and paste and run, I need this. I tried overriding paint of frame but could not be able to clear drawn components to draw the new position of the ball, I did use `graphicscontext.fillOval`