# How to clear a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a 2d game using Swing. Before, I used to render my objects and player on a jPanel over the

```
panel.repaint();
```

method and would override the paint methode in the panel class. Then I learned about the concept of moving the render code to a Render class which looks like this:

```
public class Renderer{
    public void render(Graphics g, Game game){
        game.getObjects.forEach(gameObject -> g.drawImage(....);
    }
}
```

With that code there is always a drawing on a drawing, ....
The problem with this is that I can't (or don't know how to) call the super method repaint() of the panel.
I would like to keep the Render class because the code is much more structured. Any advice on how to reset a jPanel?

I tried using panel.repaint() before calling the render method but I just got a blank screen.

```
public class Renderer {

public void render(Game game, Graphics graphics) {
    Player player = game.getPlayer();
    graphics.drawImage(player.getImage(), (int)player.getPosition().getX(), (int)player.getPosition().getY(), null);
    
}
```

}

```
public class Game{

private static Game instance;
private GamePanel gamePanel;
private Player player;
private Renderer renderer;
private boolean isRunning = true;
private final int MAX_FPS = 60;

private Game() {
    initialize();
    startGameLoop();
}

private void initialize() {
    renderer = new Renderer();
    player = Player.getInstance();
    gamePanel = GamePanel.getInstance(this);
    GameWindow.getInstance(gamePanel);
    
}

private void startGameLoop() {
    double timePerCycle = 1_000_000_000 / MAX_FPS;
    int updates = 0;
    long lastInfo = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeBefore = System.nanoTime();
    while(isRunning) {
        if(System.nanoTime() - timeBefore >= timePerCycle) {
            timeBefore = System.nanoTime();
            update();
            render();
            updates++;
        }
        
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastInfo >= 1000) {
            System.out.printf("UPS: %d\n", (updates / (( System.currentTimeMillis() - lastInfo) / 1000)));
            lastInfo = System.currentTimeMillis();
            updates = 0;
        }
    }
    
}

private void render() {
    Graphics graphics = gamePanel.getGraphics();
    renderer.render(this, graphics);
    graphics.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Please tell and show more details about your code and your problem. A [mre] would help quite a bit. Side note: usually the state of the GUI is determined by its model, the non-GUI logic code, and all the view (the GUI) is supposed to do is to display the state of the model.

Comment: Why can't you call `super.repaint()` and *then* delegate to your renderer class? Seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I have a Game class where the game-loop is located. From there I call a render method which then calls the render method within renderer class and pass the graphics object which I recieve from the panel stored in the Game class.  Deshalb kann ich repaint nicht aufrufen....

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I have no idea what you wanna say with that...

Comment: That sounds like you're entirely ignoring the *whole* Swing repaint mechanism which is probably a bad idea. I don't think you *should* be reusing the `Graphics` object you get passed in a paint call. It probably works for you, but don't think that's a supported use.

Comment: So the way you use `Graphics` is explicitly not supported/suggested. Despite this, you could probably clear the panel by just drawing a solid background color before handing work over to the renderer (or let the renderer do that as the first step).

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I already tried painting the whole panel black but that would result in a flickering window. I saw a video where someone used a canvas and with getBufferStrategy() created a non flickering window with the ability to pass graphics to Render class. But with jPanel it is not possible to get BufferStrategy so I dont know how to handle it. I believe that calling repaint() of gamePanel from the game loop  and from there using the Renderer object to render as you described is not the best way ijn terms of programming patterns?!

Answer (score 0):

To clear the panel you can employ a `boolean` in `paintComponent` and fill in the rectangle via `g.fillRect(x,y, width, height)`.

Her is one possible example. Where `boolean clearScreen` is an instance field.

```
public void clear() {
    clearScreen = true;  // tested in paintComponent
    repaint();
    clearScreen = false;
}
```

Here are some other suggestions.

- don't override `paint` for `JPanel`.  Use `paintComponent`.
- first statement should be `super.paintComponent(g)`.  This is what allows `panel.setBackground()` to work, among other things as it calls the overridden method to perform additional functionality.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // your stuff here
}
```

- Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) for controlling repaint cycles.
- painting and event handling are done in the `EventDispatch` thread.  So processing should be kept to a minimum. Any computations required for your game should be done outside that thread and when possible, only the actual invocation of the graphics methods should be done in the `paintComponent` method.
- If done properly, subsequent calls to `repaint()` will **not** add to what is there.  Each call must redraw everything including changes.

For more information check out [How to paint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

There are many examples of painting on this site.  Search for them using `[Swing]` and `[Graphics]` tags.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66832798/drawing-on-a-jpanel-from-multiple-places/66833594#66833594) is one that employs some of the above.  Also note that Swing components enable double buffering by default